# The operator '/' isn't defined for the type 'Double'. Try defining the operator '/'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, mobile-application

The operator '/' isn't defined for the type 'Double'.
Try defining the operator '/'.dart(undefined_operator)

```
 Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
    child: Text("\$${product.price! / 100}", style: TextStyle(   //error at this line
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
```

Comment: what is the datatype of product.price?

Comment: price is double

Comment: If you are absolutely positive that `price` is a double, you might want to try reinstalling Dart/Flutter.

Comment: what is the value of product.price ? have you printed the value first? Please provide the value of product.value you will get.

Comment: Does the error refer to `Double` or `double`?  The built-in type is `double`.  If you're getting an error about `Double`, then that's some other class, and you should indicate where that class comes from.

Comment: Does it work outside the string, i.e. `Text("\$"+(product.price! / 100).toString(),...`

Answer (score 0):

In case price is a String, you should parse it using
**double.parse(product.price!)**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Double to double which is the correct type, and this what solved my problem too..